# Migration in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I've an asp.net  web API connecting to SQL server with migration enabled both in the asp.net web API visual studio solution ( migration folder present in the solution)  and SQL server DBA which has the _Migration history table created.

Now, I want my asp.net web api connect to the another New dB which has the same tables along with their schema as the old dB.

I need to connect to the new dB seamlessly without creating the migration history table in the new dB. I know we can enable migration by running the update database command from the package manager console. But I need my asp.net web API to connect to the new dB with out  creating creating migration history table in the new dB.

Please suggest me how to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: "ASP.NET Web API" doesn't have anything to do with database migration - that's a concern of Entity Framework. If you just want a different database instance but with the same design then just clone the database (to preserve data) or use the "Extract data-tier application" feature in SSMS to create a database with the same schema but empty tables.

Comment: You could also `update-database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase` and remove the lines that create and update __MigrationHistory.

Comment: Could you please let me know where I've to remove the lines that create and update migration history. Does this command help me integrate with my new dB?